# ServiceStack.Redis: PopRight / PopLeft missing, instead weirdly named methods?

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack, servicestack-redis

I'm testing ServiceStack.Redis library, and at first, couldn't understand why I could not determine if I was doing pop left or pop right. At first, I only saw

```
redis.BlockingPopItemFromList("list1", null);
```

but wondered, where is the choice to pop left or right? Then I find:

```
redis.BlockingRemoveStartFromList("list1", null);
```

and also

```
redis.BlockingDequeueItemFromList("list1", null);
```

It seems that:

- `BlockingPopItemFromList` fetches and removes the oldest first, pop right
- `BlockingRemoveStartFromList` fetches and removes the newest first, pop left
- `BlockingDequeueItemFromList` fetches and removes the oldest first, pop right again

So, three separate methods, with three different names, two of which does the same thing.

Furthermore, there are these methods:

- `RemoveStartFromList`
- `BlockingRemoveStartFromList`
- `RemoveEndFromList`

but there is no `BlockingRemoveEndFromList`. I guess that is `BlockingPopx...`

Why not call it PopLeft and PopRight, or, one method Pop with parameters stating where to pop from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The APIs are given descriptive meaning to improve readability in normal code-bases for devs who are not familiar with [redis keycode commands](https://redis.io/commands).

But if you want to know the operation that each API makes just search the [github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis) source code to see what Redis command they call. Or if you're just interested in the List APIs a lot of them are defined in [RedisClient_List.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisClient_List.cs).

You'll very rarely ever want to use the `Blocking*` APIs which call [redis blocking commands](https://redis.io/commands/blpop) unless that's specifically the behavior you're after where you want to block the thread until an element has been added to the list.

The other APIs are normal operations, depending on how you want to treat the list data structure. IMO the API names are very descriptive with their behavior, e.g. if you want to treat it like a list there's:

#### Adding Items to a List

- `PrependItemToList` - prepend to the start of the list (LPUSH)
- `AddItemToList` - add an item to the end of the list (RPUSH)

#### Add range of items

- `PrependRangeToList` - prepend range of elements to the start of the list (LPUSH[])
- `AddRangeToList` - add a range of elements to the end of the list (RPUSH[])

#### Removing Items from a List

- `RemoveStartFromList` - remove an item from the start of a list (LPOP)
- `RemoveEndFromList` - remove an item from the end of a list (RPOP)

There's also aliases for the above commands if you prefer to use a different nomenclature in your code-base, like if you want to treat the list as a different data structure like a Queue or a Stack you'd instead use the paired APIs for dealing with them, i.e:

- `EnqueueItemOnList` - Enqueue the item to the queue (LPUSH)
- `DequeueItemFromList` - Dequeue the item from the queue (RPOP)

Or if you want to treat your list as a Stack:

- `PushItemToList` - Push an Item (RPUSH)
- `PopItemFromList` - Pop an Item (RPOP)

If you instead want to use your own nomenclature you can just add your own extension methods to the Redis Client interfaces, e.g:

```
public static class MyRedisApis
{
    public static string PopLeft(this IRedisClient client, string listId) =>
        client.RemoveStartFromList(listId);

    public static string PopRight(this IRedisClient client, string listId) =>
        client.RemoveEndFromList(listId);
}
```

Where you can now use your own named APIs in your code-base instead:

```
var item = redis.PopLeft(myList);
```

When needed you can cast your Redis Client to an [IRedisNativeClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Redis/IRedisNativeClient.cs) and get access to the same command names as on redis-server, but would need to convert the raw `byte[]` type to UTF-8 `string` where appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Though, I have never seen duplicate method names for the same function/usage, just to give them more options for the method name, that is a new one =) You said that "You'll very rarely ever want to use the Blocking* APIs" but how do you then solve a case where u have x number of consumers and one and only one should receive a specific message? I know there is an OnMessage event, but that is received by all consumers and I see now way of making sure that only one gets each message.

Comment: @Ted blocking isn't going to help, [BLPOP](https://redis.io/commands/blpop) is exactly like [LPOP](https://redis.io/commands/lpop) but blocks until there's an element to remove from the list. Every Redis Operation is atomic so 1 message can only be received by exactly 1 consumer. If you need a message to go to a specific consumer then both the message and consumer need to send and removed from a unique list, which is how the [Redis MQ Request + Reply Pattern](https://docs.servicestack.net/redis-mq#request--reply-mq-pattern) works.

Comment: I have tested this. If I listen to the the OnMessage event in IRedisPubSubServer, all consumers /listeners receive the message. If I use the blocking api in IRedisClient, only one receive it.

Comment: And if not using blocking api, then what, polling?

Comment: @Ted IRedsPubSubServer uses Redis Pub/Sub so every subscriber is going to receive the message posted to the topic they’re subscribed to, but yeah you can poll or block with a timeout in this case (difference between Redis MQ Get/GetAsync)